# Diameter of a rooted k-ary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm trying to find a linear-time algorithm using recursion to solve the diameter problem for a rooted k-ary tree implemented with adjacency lists. The diameter of a tree is the maximum distance between any couple of leaves. If I choose a root `r` (that is, a node whose degree is > 1), it can be shown that the diameter is either the maximum distance between two leaves in the same subtree or the maximum distance between two leaves of a path that go through `r`. My pseudocode for this problem:

```
Tree-Diameter(T,r)
    if degree[r] = 1 then
        height[r] = 0
        return 0
    for each v in Adj[r] do
        for i = 1 to degree[r] - 1 do
            d_i = Tree-Diameter(T,v)
    height[r] = max_{v in Adj[r]} (height[v]
    return max(d_i, max_{v in V} (height[v]) + secmax_{v in V} (height[v], 0) + 1)
```

To get linear time, I compute the diameter AND the height of each subtree at the same time. Then, I choose the maximum quantity between the diameters of each subtrees and the the two biggest heights of the tree + 1 (the `secmax` function chooses between `height[v]` and `0` because some subtree can have only a child: in this case, the second biggest height is `0`). I ask you if this algorithm works fine and if not, what are the problems? I tried to generalize an algorithm that solve the same problem for a binary tree but I don't know if it's a good generalization.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is V (capital)?  Is it the same as Adj[r]?

Comment: Nope. V is the set that contains all the nodes of the tree T.

Comment: Since your max_{v in V} (...) is doesn't depend on r, I assume you are calculating that separately and not for each recursion.

Comment: The problem is just the height, I don't know how to check it recursively :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a python implementation of what I believe you are interested in.  Here, a tree is represented as a list of child trees.

```
def process(tree):
  max_child_height=0
  secmax_child_height=0
  max_child_diameter=0
  for child in tree:
    child_height,child_diameter=process(child)
    if child_height>max_child_height:
      secmax_child_height=max_child_height
      max_child_height=child_height
    elif child_height>secmax_child_height:
      secmax_child_height=child_height
    if child_diameter>max_child_diameter:
      max_child_diameter=child_diameter
  height=max_child_height+1
  if len(tree)>1:
    diameter=max(max_child_diameter,max_child_height+secmax_child_height)
  else:
    diameter=max_child_diameter
  return height,diameter

def diameter(tree):
  height,diameter=process(tree)
  return diameter
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not so used to Python but I think I have understood the implementation. Only a thing: the process() function returns a pair (height,diameter), isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

In all in tree for finding diameter do as below:

1. Select a random node **A**, run BFS on this node, to find furthermost node from **A**. name this node as **S**.
2. Now run BFS starting from **S**, find the furthermost node from **S**, name it **D**.

Path between **S** and **D** is diameter of your tree. This algorithm is O(n), and just two time traverses tree. Proof is little tricky but not hard. (try yourself or if you think is not true, I'll write it later). And be careful I'm talking about Trees not general graphs. (There is no loop in tree and is connected).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already found the solution that uses BFS and I also have proof that it works.  I was looking for the solution that uses recursion. I'm trying to collect all the possible approaches to this problem :)

Comment: @QAndy, again you can use similar approach with DFS, why you just looking for recursion? Currently I don't have time, but later , I'll read your approach and say my opinion about its correctness.

Comment: @Dree would you still happen to have to link to the solution that uses BFS and its proof?

Comment: @Dree EDIT: Actually, I implemented the code myself, so it's just the proof I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is the recursive solution with Java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DiameterOrNAryTree {

    public int diameter(Node root) {
        Result result = new Result();
        getDepth(root, result);
        return result.max;
    }

    private int getDepth(Node node, Result result) {
        if (node == null) return 0;
        int h1 = 0, h2 = 0;
        for (Node c : node.children) {
            int d = getDepth(c, result);
            if (d > h1) {
                h2 = h1;
                h1 = d;
            } else if (d > h2) h2 = d;
        }
        result.max = Math.max(result.max, h1 + h2);
        return h1 + 1;
    }

    class Result {
        int max;

        Result() {
            max = 0;
        }
    }

    class Node {
        public int val;
        public List<Node> children;


        public Node() {
            children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        }

        public Node(int _val) {
            val = _val;
            children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        }

        public Node(int _val, ArrayList<Node> _children) {
            val = _val;
            children = _children;
        }
    }

}
```