# Prove traversing a k-ary tree twice yields the diameter

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I've known the algorithm to find the diameter of a tree mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698344/diameter-of-a-rooted-k-ary-tree) for quite some time:

1. Select a random node A
2. Run BFS on this node to find furthermost node from A. name this node as S.
3. Now run BFS starting from S, find the furthermost node from S, name it D.
4. Path between S and D is diameter of the tree.

But why does it work?

---

I would accept both **Ivan**'s and **coproc**'s answer if I can. These are 2 very different approaches that both answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you've completed steps 1 and 2 and have found S, and that there is no diameter in the tree that includes S. Pick a diameter PQ of the tree. You basically have to check the possible cases and in all of them, find that either PS or SQ is at least as long as PQ - which would be a contradiction.

In order to systematically check all cases, you can assume that the tree is rooted at A. Then the shortest path between any two vertices U and V is calculated in the following way - let W be the lowest common ancestor of U and V. Then the length of UV is equal to the sum of the distances between U and W and between V and W - and, in a rooted tree, these distances are just differences in the levels of the nodes (and S has a maximum level in this tree).

Then analyze all possible positions S could take with respect to the subtree rooted at W (lowest common ancestor of P and Q) and the vertices P and Q. For example, the first case is simple - S is not in the subtree rooted at W. Then, we can trivially improve the path by selecting the one of P and Q that is more distant to the root, and connecting it to the S. The rest of the cases are similar.

Comment: When S is in the subtree, it is either in the left subtree of W or the right subtree of W. P and Q must be in different parts. Therefore, either S-P or S-Q must be as long as P-Q.

Answer (score 4):

say `S = [A - B - C - D - ... X - Y - Z]` is the diameter of the tree.

consider each node in `S`, say `@`, start from it and go "away" from the diameter, there won't be a longer chain than `min(length(@, A), length(@, Z))`.

so dfs from any node on the tree, it will ends at `A` or 'Z', i.e. one end of the diameter, dfs again from it will of course lead you to the other side of the tree.

refer to this

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort providing the graph. The problem is, both "there won't be a longer chain than min(length(@, A), length(@, Z))." and "so dfs from any node on the tree, it will ends at A or 'Z'" are not true. A counter example can be easily given. Consider a perfect binary tree.

Comment: @Haozhun if the chain is longer, the diameter could be increased with it

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm works for any acyclic graph (a tree being a special acyclic graph in that it has a root).

A proof can be constructed by choosing any two additional points S2 and D2 and showing that their distance d(S2,D2) ≤ d(S,D). From the algorithm we know

- by step 2: d(A,S)≥d(A,D), d(A,S)≥d(A,S2), d(A,S)≥d(A,D2) and
- by step 3: d(S,D)≥d(S,A), d(S,D)≥d(S,S2), d(S,D)≥d(S,D2).

By distinguishing at most 5 cases (e.g. the paths SD and S2D2 have no edge in common, the paths SD and S2D2 have edges in common and A is connected to the edges running to S, etc. see image below) one can decompose the above distances into sub-paths and rewrite the inequalities based on the sub-paths. The conclusion follows from simple algebra. The details are left to the reader as an exercise. :-)

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. But I don't quite get your answer. I don't get the 5 cases you mentioned.

Comment: I have added a sketch for the two mentioned cases. From the second case 3 more similar cases have to be distinguished depending on how A is connected to the sub-graph connecting S,D,S2,D2 (e.g. on the edges going towards S2 or D or D2). Note that intermediate nodes have been omitted and that the drawn lengths have no meaning. Note also that special cases like A=A1, A1=A2, A=S, etc. do not need to be further distinguised.

Comment: In the right sketch, aside from A on S/S2/D/D2, there's actually another case where a on the common edge. But this case and the case of D, the case of D2 are actually the same.

Comment: In the left sketch, the sketch shows A in between A1 and A2. But A may be above A1 or below A2 (above and below in respect to the way this sketch is drawn). However, that doesn't change any inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your exercises. I've got it. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't tag both your answer and Ivan's as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few lemmas/facts before we get started with proof.

1. T is a tree so there is exactly 1 path between any 2 pair of vertices.
2. If S--D is the diameter then a BFS with source as S (or D) will end up giving D (or S) the largest distance. (*By definition of diameter*)

Also lets define |XY| to be the length of the path X--Y.

Define |XX| = 0.

Let A be the random node selected by the algorithm. 
After Step 2 let the furthest node got be P. 
If P is either S or D then using *Lemma 2* we are done. So we must show that P has to be either S or D.

Claim : If S--D is the diameter, then P is either S or D.

Proof: I am going to prove the above by proving the Contrapositive. The proof is for a tree with a unique diameter but it should work with minor changes (mostly the equalities) for non-unique diameters too.

**If P is neither S nor D then S--D is not the diameter.**

Assume P is neither S nor D.

**Case 1: The Path A--P intersects S--D**

[image]

Let the point of intersection be K. We know that BFS marked P as the farthest node from A and from *Lemma 1*.

```
 |AP| > |AS| 
 |AK| + |KP| > |AK| + |KS|
```

Therefore we get |KP| > |KS|.

Similarly |KP| > |KD|.

Now we consider the path SP

```
 |SP| = |SK| + |KP|
 |SP| > |SK| + |KD|
 |SP| > |SD|
```

So SP is longer than the diameter which means SD is NOT the diameter.

**Case 2:The Path A--P does NOT intersects S--D**

[image]

Now we know BFS marked P as the farthest node. So we have

```
 |AP| > |AD|
 |AP| > |AS|
```

We can write |AD| = |AK| + |KD| where K is one of the vertices in the diameter (including S and D). Similarly |AS| = |AK| + |KS|.

Without loss of generality assume |AD|>=|AS|

```
 |AK| + |KD| >= |AK| + |KS|
 |KD| >= |KS|
```

Now consider the path PD

```
 |PD| = |AP| + |AD|
 |PD| = |AP| + |AK| + |KD|
 |PD| > |AP| + |KD|          (|AK| > 0 since A cannot be on the diameter)
 |PD| > |KD| + |KD|          (|AP| > |KD|)
 |PD| > |SK| + |KD|          (|KD| >= |KS|)
 |PD| > |SD|
```

So SD is not the diameter and hence the claim.

Comment: The way you described case 2 is incorrect because (AD or AS) intersect AP may not be empty. But the idea is simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Set s represents the nodes along the diameter of the tree, with A and Z being the end nodes, and the distance from A to Z is the diameter.  For any node, n, that is a member of s the longest possible path from n will end in either A or Z.  Now if you pick a rand node in the tree, v, it either is a member of the set, or it has a path to a node, n, in this set.  Since the longest path from n is either A or Z and the path from v to n can not be longer than either the path from n to A or n to Z (if it was then v would have to be a member of the set) then running BFS on any node V will first find either A or Z, and the subsequent call will find the complementary end point.  Not a math girl, just throwing out thoughts.